# BluetoothSerial.write("SomeText") not working (React Native and react-native-bluetooth-serial)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bluetooth

I am working on a Bluetooth Serial connection over ***React Native*** application and ***Raspberry Pi***. I am using [`react-native-bluetooth-serial-2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bluetooth-serial-2) npm package in my project to establish the bluetooth serial connection.

So far the connection is established as well as data from ***Raspberry Pi*** to my ***React Native*** app is being sent.I am receiving the data using this code:

```
BluetoothSerial.on('read', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
BluetoothSerial.withDelimiter('\n').then(() => {
  console.log('Bluetooth subscribed with delimiter');
});
```

But when I try to send the data from my ***React Native*** app to ***Raspberry Pi*** using `BluetoothSerial.write("SomeText")` Nothing seems to work.

I even tried this function :

```
BluetoothSerial.write(
  'start',
  (success) => {
    console.log('Connection Successful!!: ', success);
  },
  (failure) => {
    console.log('Connection Failure!!: ', failure);
  },
);
```

to see if i get any failure results, even that didn't work.

Can someone help me with this please!!

Thank You!!

Comment: What is the code on the Raspberry Pi receiving the data you write?  Does that work if you use another app such as [Serial Bluetooth Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal)?

Comment: This link https://github.com/kuri65536/python-for-android/blob/master/python-modules/pybluez/examples/simple/rfcomm-server.py for that.

And thank you I have solved the problem will be posting the answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad I just had to call the `BluetoothSerial.write()` inside the `BluetoothSerial.on('read', (data) => { console.log(data); });` function.

Thank You!!